# Is there a way to get a list of upcoming live streams, by tag?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

We're trying to create a website that gives a list of all upcoming live streams by multiple channels that have agreed to use the same hashtag in their description.

I don't seem to be able to cobble together the right API calls to make this happen.

First when using the YouTube /v3/search API, there does not seem to be a way to query by tags. You can do a raw query of a word, but what we need to do is to find all live streams with an actual #tag in their description.

Second, when searching for upcoming videos, what you get back is the publish date, not the scheduled date for the stream itself.

I've taken a search, and then done a subsequent search of all videos matching the ids from the first search and gotten their information.

But it seems as though the upcoming search is returning some old videos.

For example, here's a snippet from a result from a query run on 12/27/2021

```
{

  "channelTitle": "EZ Craps Nation",
  "liveBroadcastContent": "upcoming",
  "publishTime": "2020-05-23T00:51:23Z"
}
```

How can a video published in May be seen as "upcoming" in December?

Here's a sample call to the search API:

`/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&eventType=upcoming&type=video&maxResults=25&order=Date&q=%23crapsnation&key=[my key here]`

Notice the old dates

If you query those results individually by video ID, you'll see that these have all appeared in the past, and many of them are no longer available.

Is there a way to achieve this seemingly simple report that I'm not seeing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I tried searching in YouTube main site and I couldn't get results with the hasthtag, then, I use again the search API - [sample](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list?apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%5B%22id%2Csnippet%22%5D%2C%22eventType%22%3A%22upcoming%22%2C%22maxResults%22%3A10%2C%22order%22%3A%22date%22%2C%22q%22%3A%22crapsnation%22%2C%22type%22%3A%5B%22video%22%5D%7D) - and yeah, I got "older" results; probably those upcoming videos are not *public* OR that channel doesn't have any upcoming videos?

Comment: Curious enough, the response to the sample I provided you says: `"pageInfo":{"totalResults": 24,"resultsPerPage": 2},` = the response does not have a `nextPageToken`, so, I don't know why the rest of the items are not shown. Also, in my few test only a reduced amount of upcoming videos has hashtags on their titles: I found 2 videos: one with (it seems) japanese characters (*example: #ししらみダイパ並走* - video_id: i1XVEf6JKnY) and other with , but, in hindi (*example: #gkinhindi* - video_id: Fnx0t5pLsXs).

Answer (score 1):

*After making my tests [as I commented before in your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70501696/is-there-a-way-to-get-a-list-of-upcoming-live-streams-by-tag#comment124667477_70501696)* - My suggestion is:

- Make again the `search` request, but, *without* the `#` character, then, you have to get extract from the results of the request those items (*i.e. videos*) whose date is greater than today's.

Example:

> I tried with `kson` = which has another upcoming video (*originally
> `#kson`*) - and got two upcoming videos, but, only one of them is at `2021-12-29T17:01:48Z` (video_id: *rYCkarUieCY*)` - [see yourself the
> results](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list?apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%5B%22id%2Csnippet%22%5D%2C%22eventType%22%3A%22upcoming%22%2C%22maxResults%22%3A10%2C%22order%22%3A%22date%22%2C%22q%22%3A%22kson%22%2C%22type%22%3A%5B%22video%22%5D%7D).

Results from the [linked request sample](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list?apix_params=%7B%22part%22%3A%5B%22id%2Csnippet%22%5D%2C%22eventType%22%3A%22upcoming%22%2C%22maxResults%22%3A10%2C%22order%22%3A%22date%22%2C%22q%22%3A%22kson%22%2C%22type%22%3A%5B%22video%22%5D%7D):

```
{
  "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
  "etag": "h1HwYzzYjQfu5rmpC-vBg5rOKwo",
  "regionCode": "CO",
  "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": 62,
    "resultsPerPage": 2
  },
  "items": [
    {
      "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
      "etag": "-tWMVFRq6tj5ZcUnfUrlhWCmybc",
      "id": {
        "kind": "youtube#video",
        "videoId": "rYCkarUieCY"
      },
      "snippet": {
        "publishedAt": "2021-12-29T17:01:48Z",// <= same date as "publishTime" attribute bellow.
        "channelId": "UC9ruVYPv7yJmV0Rh0NKA-Lw",
        "title": "ゆったり、まったりCHIT CHAT",
        "description": "スパ茶たくさんいただいていたので読むです！みなさん本当に有難う   こんにちは、kson(けいそん)といいます。本職はとある組織の組長、 ...",
        "thumbnails": {
          "default": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/rYCkarUieCY/default_live.jpg",
            "width": 120,
            "height": 90
          },
          "medium": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/rYCkarUieCY/mqdefault_live.jpg",
            "width": 320,
            "height": 180
          },
          "high": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/rYCkarUieCY/hqdefault_live.jpg",
            "width": 480,
            "height": 360
          }
        },
        "channelTitle": "kson ONAIR",
        "liveBroadcastContent": "upcoming",
        "publishTime": "2021-12-29T17:01:48Z" // <= see the publish time here.
      }
    },
    {
      "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
      "etag": "kPXEPuB_-KrYvGAqEXbRxHQkJoM",
      "id": {
        "kind": "youtube#video",
        "videoId": "3101jG7sIAs"
      },
      "snippet": {
        "publishedAt": "2021-11-30T06:50:48Z",
        "channelId": "UC9ruVYPv7yJmV0Rh0NKA-Lw",
        "title": "PLACE to CHAT",
        "description": "FREE CHAT こんにちは、kson(けいそん)といいます。本職はとある組織の組長、趣味でよく配信しています。 世界で一番ピザと龍が如くと ...",
        "thumbnails": {
          "default": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/3101jG7sIAs/default_live.jpg",
            "width": 120,
            "height": 90
          },
          "medium": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/3101jG7sIAs/mqdefault_live.jpg",
            "width": 320,
            "height": 180
          },
          "high": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/3101jG7sIAs/hqdefault_live.jpg",
            "width": 480,
            "height": 360
          }
        },
        "channelTitle": "kson ONAIR",
        "liveBroadcastContent": "upcoming",
        "publishTime": "2021-11-30T06:50:48Z"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```